# Load testing JavaScript Widget?

Tags: javascript, load-testing

I am trying to figure out how to load test my JavaScript widget. It will be running on around 1000 websites each with about 2k visitors a day so i really need to find a way to test this scenario before letting my users install the widget.

Any ideas what approach i should take?

Comment: Is the widget fetching resources from outside or just working independently?

Comment: Each time the widget loads its quering a mysql db to gather some data

Comment: Sounds like it's not the widget that needs load testing but your server.

Comment: I don't have enough info to give an answer, but there are plenty of load testing tools. You can cheaply spin up a few Amazon machines for the duration of the test, and just keep hitting the server until you get the answer you want. You should cache your results, don't do a database lookup for each request unless you really really need to.

Comment: I really need to make a db lookup each request cause its live data, widget should not always be displayed :/

Comment: That's fine, if you need to then you need to. But you may find some kind of protective barrier, whether it's cache or a rate-limiting will be required as a result of your tests. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the widget itself (an instance of your javascript code running in a browser) will never be used by more than one user (one browser) at a time. Your server-side APIs, OTOH, will. So you need to test your server by simulating the level of HTTP traffic to your server that you expect the use of your widget to generate. For this, you want web load testing tools.

Depending on how simple the APIs are, you may be fine with something like JMeter. If the API usage is more complex, you might want a more sophisticated tool.